# Supersized: external link to a specific photo?

Tags: jquery, supersized

I'm using the [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) jQuery plugin for an image gallery.

How can I link to a specific image in a supersized gallery from an external page?

Here is my code from jquery page:

jQuery(function($){

```
 $.supersized({

slideshow:   1, 
autoplay: 0,            
start_slide : document.write (location
                                .hash
                                .replace(/^#/,'')
                                  .replace(/im=([0-9]+).*$/,'$1')),

stop_loop: 0,           
random: 0,
```

....etc......
    slide_links:'num',
    thumb_links:    1,
    thumbnail_navigation:   0,
    slides:[

{image : 'photos/BE_oct14-4.jpg', title : 'slide0', thumb : '', url : ''},
{image : 'photos/cinqueterre-4.jpg', title : 'slide1', thumb : '', url : ''},

and the link from the external html page:  < href="photos.html#im=3>

Answer (score 1):

You can add external pictures as you add local pictures to your slides array:

```
slides : [
    {image : 'http://externalURL/pic01.jpg', title : 'pic01', thumb : 'http://externalURL/pic01T.jpg', url : 'http://anyUrl'},
    {image : 'http://externalURL/pic02.jpg', title : 'pic02', thumb : 'http://externalURL/pic02T.jpg', url : 'http://anyUrl'},
    {image : 'localPath/pic01.jpg', title : 'pic01_l', thumb : 'localPath/pic01T.jpg', url : 'http://anyUrl'}
]
```